# Como identificar qual link disparou um .hover()?

Tags: jquery, html

Não estou conseguindo usar o `this` aqui, pra ele identificar qual dos links eu estou passando o mouse, quando passo o mouse em um dos links ele ativa os dois links e isso não é pra acontecer. Também estou com problemas ao esconder `.post-prev` e `.post-next`.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn-abs prev-new hide show_post">&#9668;</a>
<a href="#" class="btn-abs next-new hide show_post">&#9658;</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".post-prev, .post-next").hide();

    $('.show_post').hover(function(){
        $('.post-prev, .post-next').animate({width: '20%'}, 300).show();
    }, function(){
        //$('.post-prev, .post-next').animate({width: '0'}, 300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sempre que passar o mouse por cima de um, vc reseta pra não visível os dois e depois apenas faz o efeito no item que está recebendo  hover  **this**.

Ao esconder, esconde apenas o item que vc saiu **this** ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show_post').hover(function(){
        $(".post-prev:visible, .post-next:visible").hide();

        $(this).animate({width: '20%'}, 300).show();
    }, function(){
        $(this).animate({width: '0'}, 300).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Bom eu coloquei visibility:hidden; nas classes .post-prev e .post-next até que funciona como deveriam o problema é que quando eu tiro o mouse de cima ele some também com a setinha que ativa o efeito

Comment: Coloca seu código no JSFIDDLE.COM que da pra analisar

Comment: segue http://jsfiddle.net/pabloworks/dZQLJ/